# Flutter showing the following error: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'E:\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\kotlin\flutter.gradle.kts' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  Failed to load compiled script from classpath [C:\Users\Dines.gradle\caches\jars-9\21ea282662b96e1a18c1e23f6044725d\classes.jar].

> Program

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

I tried to clear my cache. This error is not only showing in this flutter project but all the flutter projects I've created. The VS code working properly and I was afk for 30 minutes after that this error popped up. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found. So for windows the openJDK platform binary is running in the background so end the task. Then go to .gradle > cache > then delete the folder the error is showing. After these steps the issue was resolved. If anyone gets the same kind of error kindly use this method. (Cause of error: The file classes.jar got corrupted for some reason). Thank you.